# nifi expression syntax substringAfterLast nested

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to extract ES7600 from following flowfilename  FILE.IMITS.ES7600.D170614
I am trying to avoid substring and have been trying with neested
substringBeforeLast

```
${filename:substringBeforeLast(${filename:substringBeforeLast('.')})('.')}
```

But i cannot get the syntax correct. Is this posible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this filename : `FILE.IMITS.ES7600.D170614` the following attribute expression

```css
${filename:substringBeforeLast('.'):substringAfterLast('.')}
```

will return `ES7600`